# Python transform synchronous request into asynchronous to download image (httpio)

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm using synchronous responses to get image data from a url into bytes format. But I would like to make it an asynchronous process. My approach is changing python requests for httpio. to achieve it.

My original code, which is working throws the following result

[image]

### My Dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
            "uuid": {
                0: 86240171628346,
                1: 165887752774427,
                2: 175393314389900,
                3: 273714316578343,
                4: 167563092160852,
            },
            "raw_logo_url": {
                0: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOYM0psiirjiZltDUm5xPtxtsdEUVIEIR4UGZMDMxNEmS8Fmr1N4ttV5db5lpJOeI0d64&usqp=CAU",
                1: "https://cdn.logojoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/01104813/1268-768x591.png",
                2: "https://res.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,f_auto,q_auto:eco,dpr_1/v1444818641/snpqz6rutxy7azidex5w.png",
                3: "https://res.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,f_auto,q_auto:eco,dpr_1/uymioczowxzwibevii1b",
                4: "https://www.companyfolders.com/blog/media/2015/01/adidas-300x207.jpg",
            },
            "version": {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
        }
        )
```

### Synchronous version

```
def get_image_from_url(url: str) -> Union[PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile, JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile]:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # print(response.content[:100])
        return Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
    print(response.status_code)
    return None


def convert_image_to_bytes(image: Union[PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile, JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile]) -> bytes:
    """
    Receives a PIL image file and returns a bytes object
    """
    b = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(b, 'png')
    image_bytes = b.getvalue()
    return image_bytes


def process_image_from_url(url: str) -> bytes:
    image = get_image_from_url(url)
    return convert_image_to_bytes(image)

df["company_logo"] = df["raw_logo_url"].apply(process_image_from_url)
```

### Asynchronous version, not working

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import pandas as pd


async def get_image_from_url_(url: str) -> Union[PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile, JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile]:
    
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.get(url)

        if response.status == 200:
            print(response.__dict__.keys())
            return response.text()
            # return Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.read()))
    print(response.status)
    return None


async def process_image(df: pd.DataFrame, input_column: str = 'raw_logo_url', output_column: str = 'company_logo'):
    df[output_column] = await asyncio.gather(*[get_image_from_url(v) for v in df[input_column]])
    print(df)

df2 = asyncio.run(process_image(df))
```

#### Issue

In the async response I cannot get the `response.content` that I want to transform into an image to make a bytes object later.

```
*** TypeError: unhashable type: 'JpegImageFile'
```

Notice that every image is transformed into `PNG` in the original execution

Comment: Please try to add `await` before `response.text()` at the `get_image_from_url_` function.

Comment: Same issue :/ *** TypeError: unhashable type: 'JpegImageFile'

Comment: I figured it out. The above code contains a typo. Please change the `get_image_from_url` to `get_image_from_url_`, but it was not the cause of the error. You should change `return await response.text()` to `return await response.read()`.